# Converting Unichar to Int Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, unichar

I've got a strange problem trying to convert from unichar to int:

I have a String containing a few numbers, like `@"12345"`. This numbers I want to save individually, meaning I want 5 numbers, 1, 2, 3, ... . Now, while

```
NSLog(@"Value: %C", [myString characterAtIndex:0]);
```

returns

```
Value: 1
```

This:

```
NSLog(@"Value: %@", [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:[myString characterAtIndex:0]]);
```

returns

```
Value: 49
```

I would really appreciate some help, Fabian

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the code above, you're getting exactly what you're asking for; the numeric value of the character `'1'` is 49, and you're creating an NSNumber from that.

If what you want is `1`, then you can can take advantage of the fact that the digits 0-9 are laid out in order in the ASCII/UTF-8 tables and subtract an appropriate value from the unichar you receive.

Try out this code snippet to get you started in the right direction:

```
NSString *s = @"0123456789";
for (int i = 0; i < [s length]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Value: %d", [s characterAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you! Basically, I just subtract 48 from my char and get the desired result... Thought there was a more straightforward way than that :)