# How to view each element from a string or data using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, bluetooth, arduino

I'm creating an [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_%28Apple%29) application that receives an input from a force sensor. The Arduino is connected to a BLE [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) transmitter, that sends a data stream of information to the application.

Below is my code:

```
-(void) bleDidReceiveData:(unsigned char *)data length:(int)length
{
    NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:length];
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.label.text = s;

    if (s>150){
        [UIImageView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
        [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:0.01];
        [ImageView setAlpha:1];
        [UIImageView commitAnimations];
    }
    else {
        //remove red
        [UIImageView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
        [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [ImageView setAlpha:0];
        [UIImageView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

I had two questions:

- The Bluetooth subsystem sends a stream of data (d) which is a set of numbers representing force impacts on the force sensor. Is there any way for me to go into each element of d or the converted string, `s`, so that I can use it in my if statement?
  I need to display the image if any number in the string is above a threshold (the `if` statement). Or can I directly use the string in the `if` statement?
  I would imagine this would require a for loop. I am just not sure how to set it up.
- To get the threshold, I need to calibrate the force sensor. Is there a way that I can get the mode or average of the data stream or string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a gap or some sort of *separator* (such as a '-' or '/') between the data stream:

- use [NSString componentsSeparatedByString] to split the string into it's constituent parts
- then use [NSString floatValue] on each separated string to get the number
- compare this value to your threshold in your if statement, show your image if necessary.

If there is *no* separator in your data stream then there are two options:

1) convert to NSString as you do already, then use characteratIndex[n] inside a for loop to get each character. To convert each returned unichar to a number, you'll need to do some jiggerypokery. See these two threads:

[Objective-C NSString for loop with characterAtIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315435/objective-c-nsstring-for-loop-with-characteratindex)

[Converting Unichar to Int Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179082/converting-unichar-to-int-problem)

2) if you know how many bytes are taken up by each value you may be able to skip the NSString completey and use [NSData subDataWithRange:] (inside a for loop) to extract the data and convert to a value.

Good luck!

Comment: The first method works, I have '-' seperating each data point. Thank You!

I had a second questions. The data from the arduino is sent as a number (anywhere between 0-500). It displays as characters and random numbers on the application. I know this has to do with the encoding; is there any different encoding I can use in my NSString...encoding: ______     
Just so that numbers are displayed. Or can I convert the encoded string into one that displays numbers.